# Understanding passing addresses to functions and also functions returning pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to understand functions pass by reference and functions returning pointers. i have a following code which throws compile time error:

> "error: incompatible type for argument 1 of `jamboree'";

here is the code i'm trying to compile.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main () {

float p = 23.5, *q;
float jamboree(float);
q = &p;
printf ("before call = %d\n", q);
q = jamboree(&p);
printf ("after call = %d\n", q);

}
float jamboree(float *i){
i = i + 1;
return(i);
}
```

the same code modified for "Functions returning pointers" which works fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main () {

float p = 23.5, *q;
float *jamboree(float *);
q = &p;
printf ("before call = %d\n", q);
q = jamboree(&p);
printf ("after call = %d\n", q);

}
float *jamboree(float *i){
i = i + 1;
return(i);
}
```

output for above code is:

```
before call = 2673932
after call = 2673936
```

Q1. why do i get incompatible type for argument 1 for the first code (which is pass by referance).

Comment: How is the first code pass-by-reference?

Comment: In the first code, you have declared that the first argument is expected to be float - `float jamboree(float);`

Comment: sending the addresses of variable as argument: e.g jamboree(&p);

Comment: @SilentMonk, Yes where 'p' is also declared as float,

Comment: @praneeth, but you are passing the address of a float, i.e you are passing the reference while you declaration suggests that you are passing by value. Dave M's answer provides a detailed explanation.

Comment: @praneeth `p` is a float, but `&p` is not. And you are passing &p, not p.

Comment: Don't put function prototypes at block scope, it means the compiler will not detect a mismatch. Put it before `main` and the compiler will then tell you about this error.

Comment: Please edit your post and fix the indention.

Answer (score 4):

Your declaration of `jamboree()` at line 5 says you're going to pass a `float`, but the definition of `jamboree()` at line 12 says you're going to pass a *pointer* to float.  So the declaration and definition don't agree, and you get an error.  In your "pointers to function" version, the declaration and definition agree.

Comment: so if i change my declaration to `float jamboree(float *);` should it be working ??

Comment: It will fix the "incompatible type" error, but cause a different error.  You probably want to change the definition to `float jamboree(float i)`.  That will be closer to doing something useful, although you may have noticed that the printout from your "pointers to function" version doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "functions returning pointers," as @praneeth called the second code example.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs...I got it.

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration and defination doesn't match in first code. In first code you declare :

```
float jamboree(float);
```

This means that in jamboree function you are sending float value and returning float value.
But when you implemented function :

```
float jamboree(float *i){
i = i + 1;
return(i);
}
```

You are receiving float pointer and returning float value. Which is different from the declaration. Therefore you will get a compiler error.

Comment: so if i change my declaration to float jamboree(float *); should it be working ??

Comment: Yes.. it should work but not logical.. because you are assigning float value to the `q` which is pointer.. Pointer always assigned with address value.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to add a commit, so I write my answer here. What I want to say is despite the problem pointed out above: *Your declaration and defination doesn't match*, there's also type match problem with the function.

```
float jamboree(float *i){
    i = i + 1;
    return(i);
}
```

You return a `float *` type, and the type expected is `float`. Because `i = i+1` is the next pointer address.